# PHP form working intermittently

Tags: javascript, php, forms, http-post

Up until recently, a basic HTML form using POST with PHP has worked fine. Currently, it is mailing perfectly from some computers/devices, but failing with certain others.

Some devices outside the upload network submit fine, others not. Sometimes one computer that had issues worked just fine the next attempt. My instinct says it's a webhost issue, as I'm utilizing the free byethost17.

This is the PHP:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$ride = $_POST['rideA'] +$_POST['rideS'];
$frogs = $_POST['bbq'] + $_POST['burg'] + $_POST['chim'] + $_POST['ces'] + $_POST['fet'];
$top = $_POST['topA'] + $_POST['topS'] + $_POST['topSt'];
$memo = $_POST['memA'] + $_POST['memS'] + $_POST['memSt'];
$fee =  max($_POST['flight'], $_POST['bus'], $ride, $_POST['cruise'], $_POST['srock'], $frogs, $top, $memo);
$ambrosia = $fee * 30;
$subtotal = (618 * $_POST['flight']) + (30 * $_POST['bus']) + (65 * $_POST['rideA']) + (45 * $_POST['rideS']) + (60 * $_POST['cruise']) + (95 * $_POST['srock']) + (19 * $frogs) + (26 * $_POST['topA']) + (24 * $_POST['topS']) + (20 * $_POST['topSt']) + (21.5 * $_POST['memA']) + (16.5 * $_POST['memS']) + (13.5 * $_POST['memSt']);
$total = $subtotal + $ambrosia;

$to = '***@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Order Confirmation: ' . $_POST['a'] . ' ' . $_POST['b']; 
$message = 'School: ' . 'CVHS' . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['a1'] . $_POST['a'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['b1'] . $_POST['b'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['c1'] . $_POST['c'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['d1'] . $_POST['d'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['e1'] . $_POST['e'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['f1'] . $_POST['f'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['g1'] . $_POST['g'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['h1'] . $_POST['h'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['flight1'] . $_POST['flight'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['bus1'] . $_POST['bus'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['rideS1'] . $_POST['rideS'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['rideA1'] . $_POST['rideA'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['cruise1'] . $_POST['cruise'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['srock1'] . $_POST['srock'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['bbq1'] . $_POST['bbq'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['burg1'] . $_POST['burg'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['chim1'] . $_POST['chim'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['ces1'] . $_POST['ces'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['fet1'] . $_POST['fet'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['topA1'] . $_POST['topA'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['topS1'] . $_POST['topS'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['topSt1'] . $_POST['topSt'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['memA1'] . $_POST['memA'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['memS1'] . $_POST['memS'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['memSt1'] . $_POST['memSt'] . "\r\n" . "\r\n";
$message .= 'The Paramount NYC' . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['ab1'] . $_POST['ab'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['ac1'] . $_POST['ac'] . ' ' . $_POST['acday'] . ', ' . $_POST['acyear'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['ad1'] . $_POST['ad'] . ' ' . $_POST['adday'] . ', ' . $_POST['adyear'] . "\r\n" . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['bb1'] . $_POST['bb'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['bc1'] . $_POST['bc'] . ' ' . $_POST['bcday'] . ', ' . $_POST['bcyear'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['bd1'] . $_POST['bd'] . ' ' . $_POST['bdday'] . ', ' . $_POST['bdyear'] . "\r\n" . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['iroom1'] . $_POST['iroom'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['aname1'] . $_POST['aname'] . ' ';
$message .= $_POST['bname1'] . $_POST['bname'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['cname1'] . $_POST['cname'] . ' ';
$message .= $_POST['dname1'] . $_POST['dname'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['ename1'] . $_POST['ename'] . ' ';
$message .= $_POST['fname1'] . $_POST['fname'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['gname1'] . $_POST['gname'] . ' ';
$message .= $_POST['hname1'] . $_POST['hname'] . "\r\n" . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['rroom1'] . $_POST['rroom'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['jname1'] . $_POST['jname'] . ' ';
$message .= $_POST['kname1'] . $_POST['kname'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['lname1'] . $_POST['lname'] . ' ';
$message .= $_POST['mname1'] . $_POST['mname'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['nname1'] . $_POST['nname'] . ' ';
$message .= $_POST['oname1'] . $_POST['oname'] . "\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['pname1'] . $_POST['pname'] . ' ';
$message .= $_POST['qname1'] . $_POST['qname'] . "\r\n";
$message .= 'Payment type: ' . $_POST['payment'] . "\r\n";
$message .= 'Sub-total: ' . $subtotal . "\r\n";
$message .= 'Ambrosia Fee: ' . $ambrosia . "\r\n";  
$message .= 'Total: ' . $total . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message);
header('Refresh: 1; URL= http://***.com');
}

?>
```

These are the js calls:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
```

This is the javascript code:

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var xa = document.forms["main"]["a"].value;
    var xb = document.forms["main"]["b"].value;
    var xc = document.forms["main"]["c"].value;
    var xd = document.forms["main"]["d"].value;
    var xe = document.forms["main"]["e"].value;
    var xf = document.forms["main"]["f"].value;
    var xg = document.forms["main"]["g"].value;
    var xh = document.forms["main"]["h"].value;

    if (xa == null || xa == "") {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
    document.forms["main"]["a"].focus();
        return false;}

    if (xb == null || xb == "") {
        alert("Last name must be filled out");
    document.forms["main"]["b"].focus();
        return false;}

    if (xc == null || xc == "") {
        alert("Phone number must be filled out");
    document.forms["main"]["c"].focus();
        return false;}

    if (xd == null || xd == "") {
        alert("Email must be filled out");
    document.forms["main"]["d"].focus();
        return false;}

    if (xe == null || xe == "") {
        alert("Street name must be filled out");
    document.forms["main"]["e"].focus();
        return false;}

    if (xf == null || xf == "") {
        alert("City must be filled out");
    document.forms["main"]["f"].focus();
        return false;}

    if (xg == null || xg == "") {
        alert("State must be filled out");
    document.forms["main"]["g"].focus();
        return false;}

    if (xh == null || xh == "") {
        alert("Zipcode must be filled out");
    document.forms["main"]["h"].focus();
        return false;}
}
</script>
```

I have no idea what could cause this outside of the webhost. Thank you!

Comment: What is the error that is thrown? does it say anything on the screen?

Comment: You're not validating your data at all, haven't explained what all of those POST fields are, and haven't provided the form HTML, so just about anything could be going wrong. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The downvotes acquired here may be due to "solve this ASAP. Please help. Please help!" - readers generally interpret this as begging and hurrying, and it does not go down well on volunteer sites. All questions are of equal importance here, and business deadlines and homework hand-in dates should not be transferred to readers.

Comment: See my comments on an answer regarding `header('Refresh: 1; URL= http://***.com')` - this is wrong, and I can't imagine this would ever work.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is the some issue with mail() function you are using. Try this [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-php-phpmailer/)

You can also try the below code.

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message)){
   echo "Email sent";
   header('Refresh: 1; URL= http://***.com');
}else{
   echo "Unable to send email";
}
```

`mail()` function returns true if the email has been sent and then you can redirect to your next page.

Let me know if this helps

Comment: If the mail is working in certain cases, I would say it's more likely to be JavaScript. Either way, that `header()` is not correct - you're mixing your HTTP headers with your meta tag values. That's a meta tag and needs to be presented in a full HTML document.

Comment: Aha! It's the OP's mistake too, apologies - nevertheless be careful when replicating mistakes, as the reader may be inclined to think you believe it all to be correct.